# Windows Server 2003 not sharing internet

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have an HP Proliant ML350 server with Windows Server 2003 for a small network (20 computers). I've been trying to share its internet connection for the past month. I tried every solution I found here and in other places. I set up RRAS to no avail (tried several settings).

It has a lan and a nic card. The client computers can find the server. I set up a shared folder and I can access it without problems. Last time I tried using the internet on client computers, I was only getting a "The website has not been set up yet" warning page.

I even changed the card property to share its internet connection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` - how can we answer that? You haven't provided any useful information, such as RRAS config, client config, error logs, etc. And why are you still using an OS that has reached end of support?

Comment: I tried all the RRAS config options (NAT, Dial-up, etc.) Server has DHCP service activated, DNS service as well and also an Active Directory. I'm still using Windows Server 2003 due to government restrictions. Clients detect IP automatically and the server address as a proxy server

Comment: "Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices. Questions that relate to **unsupported** hardware or **software platforms** or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault"

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Using an unsupported operating system released over a decade ago for a start...